# how to clear message value in jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a validator for some components which is rendered for instance as:

```
<span class="iceMsgError graValidationMessageError graNotRequiredError" id="j_id1950:selectOneMenuVdcValidator">Value is required!</span>
```

I want to clear the value in some cases and I do it like this:

```
if (component.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).contains(VALIDATORS_COMPONENT_ID)) {
        final HtmlMessage messageValidator = (HtmlMessage) component;
        //clear value here
    }
```

I simply don't find any method to clear the value... For Instance, input components have `setValue` but [HtmlMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlMessage.html#getDir%28%29) does not seem to have anything like this.

Do you know any way to do that?

`Update`: To clear input components values I do it like this: (I use this when closing some popups to clear user input)

```
if (component instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
        final EditableValueHolder editableValueHolder = (EditableValueHolder) component;
        editableValueHolder.setSubmittedValue(null);
        editableValueHolder.setValue(null);
        editableValueHolder.setLocalValueSet(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of investigation, I've found out why the messages errors were not clear when closing the popup.

There was an `immediate=true` attribute for some selectOneMenus which causes this issue. In icefaces, we use this attribute togheter with `partialSubmit=true` but here we did not need it so, staying alone, it caused this ugly issue.

So basically, there is not setter fot this because you do not need to clear up that manually in the way I wanted to do it.

I've decided to not delete this question because it can help somebody.